# Kafka Streams Avro Consumer is not able to retrieve Avro schema for id 10007

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams, avro, confluent-schema-registry, confluent-cloud

I am running a Kafka Streams Consumer that is trying to consume Avro records from Confluent Cloud. I keep getting the error: `Error retrieving Avro unknown schema for id 100007` and `unauthorized; error code: 401`. I have a `streams.properties` file in `src/main/resources/`.

Here is my error message:

```
org.apache.kafka.common.errors.SerializationException: Error retrieving Avro unknown schema for id 100007
    at io.confluent.kafka.serializers.AbstractKafkaSchemaSerDe.toKafkaException(AbstractKafkaSchemaSerDe.java:259)
    at io.confluent.kafka.serializers.AbstractKafkaAvroDeserializer$DeserializationContext.schemaFromRegistry(AbstractKafkaAvroDeserializer.java:341)
    at io.confluent.kafka.serializers.AbstractKafkaAvroDeserializer.deserialize(AbstractKafkaAvroDeserializer.java:113)
    at io.confluent.kafka.serializers.KafkaAvroDeserializer.deserialize(KafkaAvroDeserializer.java:55)
    at io.confluent.kafka.streams.serdes.avro.SpecificAvroDeserializer.deserialize(SpecificAvroDeserializer.java:66)
    at io.confluent.kafka.streams.serdes.avro.SpecificAvroDeserializer.deserialize(SpecificAvroDeserializer.java:38)
    at org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.Deserializer.deserialize(Deserializer.java:60)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.SourceNode.deserializeValue(SourceNode.java:58)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.RecordDeserializer.deserialize(RecordDeserializer.java:66)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.RecordQueue.updateHead(RecordQueue.java:176)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.RecordQueue.addRawRecords(RecordQueue.java:112)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.PartitionGroup.addRawRecords(PartitionGroup.java:303)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamTask.addRecords(StreamTask.java:960)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.TaskManager.addRecordsToTasks(TaskManager.java:1068)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamThread.pollPhase(StreamThread.java:962)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamThread.runOnce(StreamThread.java:751)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamThread.runLoop(StreamThread.java:604)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamThread.run(StreamThread.java:576)
Caused by: io.confluent.kafka.schemaregistry.client.rest.exceptions.RestClientException: Unauthorized; error code: 401
    at io.confluent.kafka.schemaregistry.client.rest.RestService.sendHttpRequest(RestService.java:297)
    at io.confluent.kafka.schemaregistry.client.rest.RestService.httpRequest(RestService.java:367)
    at io.confluent.kafka.schemaregistry.client.rest.RestService.getId(RestService.java:836)
    at io.confluent.kafka.schemaregistry.client.rest.RestService.getId(RestService.java:809)
    at io.confluent.kafka.schemaregistry.client.CachedSchemaRegistryClient.getSchemaByIdFromRegistry(CachedSchemaRegistryClient.java:277)
    at io.confluent.kafka.schemaregistry.client.CachedSchemaRegistryClient.getSchemaBySubjectAndId(CachedSchemaRegistryClient.java:409)
    at io.confluent.kafka.serializers.AbstractKafkaAvroDeserializer$DeserializationContext.schemaFromRegistry(AbstractKafkaAvroDeserializer.java:330)
    ... 16 more
```

And here is the Kafka Streams code

```java
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Properties;

import com.kinsaleins.avro.POCEntity;
import io.confluent.kafka.streams.serdes.avro.SpecificAvroSerde;
import org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.Serde;
import org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.Serdes;
import org.apache.kafka.streams.KafkaStreams;
import org.apache.kafka.streams.StreamsBuilder;
import org.apache.kafka.streams.StreamsConfig;
import org.apache.kafka.streams.kstream.Consumed;
import org.apache.kafka.streams.kstream.KStream;


public class streams {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

        StreamsBuilder builder = new StreamsBuilder();

        Properties properties = new Properties();

        InputStream in = streams.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("streams.properties");
        properties.load(in);

        properties.put(StreamsConfig.APPLICATION_ID_CONFIG, "kafka-streams-app");
        properties.put(StreamsConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, "pkc-2396y.us-east-1.aws.confluent.cloud:9092");
        properties.put(StreamsConfig.DEFAULT_KEY_SERDE_CLASS_CONFIG, Serdes.String().getClass().getName());
        properties.put(StreamsConfig.DEFAULT_VALUE_SERDE_CLASS_CONFIG, SpecificAvroSerde.class);

        final String inputTopic = properties.getProperty("producer.send.topic");

        final Map<String, String> serdeConfig = Collections.singletonMap("schema.registry.url",
            "https://psrc-4xgzx.us-east-2.aws.confluent.cloud");

        final Serde<String> stringSerde = Serdes.String();
        final Serde<POCEntity> valueAvroSerde = new SpecificAvroSerde<>();
        valueAvroSerde.configure(serdeConfig, false);


        KStream<String, POCEntity> firstStream = builder.stream(inputTopic, Consumed.with(stringSerde, valueAvroSerde));
        firstStream.peek((key, value) -> System.out.println("key " +key +"value " + value));

        KafkaStreams kafkaStreams = new KafkaStreams(builder.build(), properties);
        kafkaStreams.start();

    }

}
```

I don't understand what I am doing wrong. I have followed instructions from https://docs.confluent.io/platform/current/streams/developer-guide/datatypes.html#avro, https://docs.confluent.io/cloud/current/cp-component/streams-cloud-config.html, https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LxxeXI1mPKo,
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DOBMB0L0oKQ&list=PLa7VYi0yPIH35IrbJ7Y0U2YLrR9u4QO-s&index=4, and
https://github.com/confluentinc/kafka-streams-examples/tree/7.1.1-post/src/main/java/io/confluent/examples/streams (Looked at the avro examples for guidance).

Completely at a loss here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the error says, `Unauthorized`.

You have given no authentication settings to your avro serde config.

Notice [from docs](https://docs.confluent.io/cloud/current/cp-component/streams-cloud-config.html) - `basic.auth.credentials.source` + `schema.registry.basic.auth.user.info`. The rest of the links you've given seem to be "local development / getting started" and don't cover security configurations

Similarly, you need SASL properties in your `properties` variable to connect to the actual broker, assuming that is not part of `streams.properties` file...

Confluent Cloud requires authentication, and the values for that setting should be shown in your cluster dashboard.

If there were no authentication, anyone would be able to copy the code in your question and start sending/consuming random data ;)

Comment: I have all those properties configured in my `streams.properties`. That's why I am so confused why I keep getting an authentication error. My organization uses SSO to access Confluent Cloud does that have anything to do with this?

Comment: Wait I got it! So I commented out the connection properties in my `stream.properties` file and followed the instructions in the link you sent me. Then, I commented out lines 45-50 (where I am creating `Serde` objects), because I realized I had already configured default Serde and then I got rid of the `Consumed.with()` argument in the `.stream()` method and it worked. Thanks!

Comment: Hey I posted another question as I got stuck again with my Kafka Streams App. Would really appreciate your help again!